# Social Network Gaming on Windows, Linux and OS X

Tags: c++, social, facebook, twitter

I'm working on mobile platforms as Android, IOS... Many users of [Moblox](http://www.ellismarkov.com/moblox) ask us a windows and an OS X version.
There is no difficulties to provide these versions, because we are developing on OS X C++ code but we miss global scores and social network part (facebook, twitter). Is there any library to implement these functions on Desktops plaforms ?

On mobile platforms, we have many SDK to provide theses functions as OpenFeint, ScoreLoop, Plus+. We have used cocoslive and uploaded scores with libcurl but it's very limited.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook and Twitter provide cross-system APIs accessible in a variety of ways, typically a simple HTTP request (or a few).

Comment: Yes, i know it. But i'm searching a full packaging as OpenFeint, ScoreLoop. these solutions have great success on mobile platform so why is there anything on Desktop platform?

Comment: A mobile device usually has one language, one transport mechanism, one rendering library, one hardware setup, etc. Desktops don't have that luxury. Besides, to write such a package would take very little time - probably less time than writing the UI for it!

Comment: Also, mobile environments sometimes don't have cURL and suchlike to give you full power to access those APIs easily. There's nothing 'limited' about them at all, not sure where you got that idea from. What do you think those frameworks use?